# Strange behavior of OffsetDateTime.now() in Android

Tags: java, android, datetimeoffset

If I do in a generally Java program:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now();
```

then I have an output of **2020-04-01T20:22:04.604+02:00**.

If I do the same on Android then I have the output **2020-04-01T18:22:04.604Z**.

Also with formatting to local_time:

```
String format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME.format(now);
```

the output is **18:22:04.604**

But I want from now() my local DateTime **20.22** and not the UTC time.

The systems timezone in Android is European Summertime +02:00.

What is going on here?

Comment: I am sorry it seams the Problem is that system zone of Android Simulator is UTC if I do String zone = ZoneId.systemDefault().toString(); BUT in my settings of Android I have +02:00.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way is to pass the time zone that you want to the `now` method:

```
    OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Vienna"));
    System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

Output when I ran just now:

> 2020-04-04T09:02:05.059927+02:00

Giving time zone explicitly frees us from relying on the default time zone of the JVM.

If I understand your question correctly, the JVM time zone setting didn’t reflect the time zone setting of your device. It’s possible for the two to be different, but how that came to be in your case, I cannot tell. Possible explanations include:

- Your JVM was launched with a setting of the `user.timeaone` equal to UTC.
- Some place in your program or another program running in the same JVM the time zone is set to UTC, either by setting the above mentioned system property or by calling `TimeZone.setDefault()`.